# Why does the (deep) copy of a list consume more memory than the original list?

Tags: python

```
import sys, copy

x = [None]
y = x
c = copy.copy(x)
dc = copy.deepcopy(x)

print(x, y, c, dc)          # [None] [None] [None] [None]
print(sys.getsizeof([0]))   # 72
print(sys.getsizeof(["0"])) # 72
print(sys.getsizeof(x))     # 72
print(sys.getsizeof(y))     # 72
print(sys.getsizeof(c))     # 96
print(sys.getsizeof(dc))    # 96
```

I understand that `sys.getsizeof` ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.getsizeof)) returns the size of the container (list) itself, not considering the content, so I get that it returns the same size (**72**) for `[0], [None] and ["0"]`.

However, why would a copy or a deep copy require more memory for holding the same data (**96** instead of **72**)?

The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.getsizeof) state:

> getsizeof() calls the object’s __sizeof__ method and adds an additional garbage collector overhead if the object is managed by the garbage collector.

So the only plausible reason for the difference is that a copy is handled differently by the garbage collector, right? But why would it?

My environment: Win 10, Python 3.4.3 64 bit

Comment: I am getting sizeof(c) 72 in 3.6.6 version

Comment: I am getting sizeof(c) 64 in 3.9.13 version (same as x and y sizes), and 88 for sizeof(dc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lists use a resize policy that involves sometimes keeping spare space on the end to accommodate more elements, to guarantee amortized constant time appends. Some of your lists have more spare space on the end than others. Python doesn't promise how much spare space any list will have.

Comment: So it's kind of an implementation detail, right? I know that asking for off-site resources is off-topic, but can you link any sources where this is mentioned?

Comment: @MikeScotty: It's briefly mentioned in the [design faq](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/design.html#how-are-lists-implemented-in-cpython). I'm not aware of any other official documentation of the resize policy.

Comment: In Python 3.9.13 copy() does no more enlarge the size (see my comment below the question), but deepcopy still does. The inconsistency in the resize policy for creating new lists and copying lists is no more there. deepcopy on the other hand seem to still apply another policy than creation of new lists and copy does.