# Why is there a different result for getsizeof between list() and []

Tags: python, list, memory-management, python-internals

While working, I noticed a strange thing:

```
from sys import getsizeof as gs

list1=[1]
list2=list([1])

list1==list2 #true
gs(list1)    #80.  (I guess 72 overhead +8 of the int)
gs(list2)    #104. (I guess 72 + 8 as above + 24 of...?)


list3=[1,2,3,4,5]
list4=list(list3)

gs(list3)    #112
gs(list4)    #136
```

So there is always this 24 bytes difference, and I cannot really understand where they come from.

Is it something related to the internals, for sure, but can anyone please explain me what's happening under the hood?

Comment: Sounds similar to a question I asked some time ago: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54445004/4349415 - though I asked about the the size of a copy, not the difference in constructors, but under the hood it's probably related.

Comment: Since this is probing implementation details it would be useful (especially for verification) if you added your python-implementation and the used Python version as tags. e.g. CPython and Python-3.7 if you used CPython 3.7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR: Lists over-allocate so they can provide amortized constant-time (`O(1)`) append operations. The amount of over-allocation depends on how the list is created and the append/delete history of the instance. A list-literal always knows the size beforehand and simply doesn't over-allocate (or only slightly). The `list` function *not always knows* the length of the result because it has to iterate over the argument, so the final over-allocation depends on the used (**implementation-dependent**) over-allocation-scheme.

To understand what we're looking at it's important to know that `sys.getsizeof` reports only the size of the instance. It doesn't look at the contents of the instance. **So the size of the contents (in this case `int`s) isn't accounted for.**

What actually contributes to the size of the list is (64bit system assumed):

- 8-bytes: Reference-count.
- 8-bytes: Pointer to class.
- 8-bytes: Stores the number of elements in the list (equivalent to `len(your_list)`).
- 8-bytes: Stores the size of the array that holds the elements in the list (this is `len(your_list) + over_allocation`) .
- 8-bytes: Pointer to the array that stores pointers to the contents.
- 8-bytes per slot of the list: To hold pointers (or NULL) to each of the element in the list.
- 24-bytes: Needed for other stuff (I think garbage-collection)

That explanation is probably a bit hard to understand, so maybe it becomes clearer if I add some images (neglecting the extra 24 bytes that are used for garbage-collection). I created them based on my findings on CPython 3.7.2 Windows 64bit, Python 64bit from Anaconda.

No over-allocation, e.g. for `mylist = [1,2,3]`:

[image]

With over-allocation, e.g. for `mylist = list([1,2,3])`:

[image]

Or for manual `appends`:

```
mylist = []
mylist.append(1)
mylist.append(2)
mylist.append(3)
```

[image]

That means an empty list already takes 64 bytes, assuming empty lists have no over-allocation. For each element added another reference to a Python object has to be added (a pointer is 8 bytes).

So the minimum size of a `list` is:

```
size_min = 64 + 8 * n_items
```

Python lists are variable-sized and if it would only allocate as many space to hold the current amount of items you would have to copy the whole array whenever a new item is added (making it `O(n)`). However if you over-allocate, meaning that you actually take more memory than you would need to store the elements, then you can support amortized `O(1)` appends because it only needs to resize sometimes. See for example [Wikipedia "Amortized analysis"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amortized_analysis).

The next bit is that a literal always knows it's size, you put `x` items in the literal and at source-code parsing time it's already known how big the list has to be. So you can simply allocate the required memory for something like this:

```
l = [1, 2, 3]
```

However since `list` is a callable and Python doesn't optimize that call away even if the argument is simply a literal (I mean you could assign something different to the name `list`), it has to *really* call `list`.

`list` itself just iterates over the argument and appends the items to it's internal array, resizing when needed and over-allocating to make it amortized `O(1)`. `list` can check what size the input has, but since (theoretically) anything could happen while iterating over an object it takes that length estimate as a rough guideline, not as guarantee. So while it avoids re-allocations if it can predict the number of items in the argument it still over-allocates (just in case).

Note that all of this is **implementation-details**, it could be totally different in other Python implementations, even in different CPython versions. The only thing Python guarantees (I think it does, I'm not 100% sure) is that `append` is amortized `O(1)` and not how it is achieved and how much memory a list instance needs.

Comment: I'll note that it is somewhat odd that `list` can't (or doesn't) iterate over its argument to determine how many elements to allocate, since `str.join` does something similar. I guess it's because `list.__new__` doesn't actually look at its argument; it just allocates an empty list and passes the argument to `list.__init__` to actually populate the new list.

Comment: @chepner Yeah, what I have written is not really correct for all versions of Python. I glossed over some of the details, for example in CPython 3.7.2 [`list.extend`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.2/Objects/listobject.c#L807-L932) (which is called by [`list.__init__`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.2/Objects/listobject.c#L2625-L2658)) checks the size it just over-allocates x elements (where [x depends on the number of elements](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.2/Objects/listobject.c#L50-L63)). But that changed a few times over the last versions.

Comment: @chepner I think the main problem here is that even if you know the length of the argument when you start the iteration you cannot guarantee that the length doesn't change during iteration so the "pessimistic" approach is to allocate the "visible-length + a bit" and at least it avoided all the resizes up to that length. And having no over-allocation is also tricky (at least when looking at the performance) because the first append thereafter will be `O(n)` (this is different for strings which are immutable and probably don't do over-allocation, so `str.join` **has** to know the exact size).

Comment: @MSeifert Thanks for the explanation, the part "However since list is a callable and Python doesn't optimize that call away even if the argument is simply a literal (...), it has to really call list." really enlightened me!